# Define unnumbered theorem with template ws-ijnt.cls

Tags: environments, theorems, templates, newtheorem

The obsolete latex template `ws-ijnt.cls` (see [here](https://www.worldscientific.com/sda/1037/ijnt-2e.zip)) is incompatible with `amsthm`, `ntheorem` and part of `thmtools`. How can I define an unnumbered theorem environment with this template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
\newtheorem{nonumberthm}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\thenonumberthm}{\unskip}
```

Of course you don't want to set a `\label` in the body of such theorems. Well, you can do it, but using `\ref` would be meaningless.